# Group non-connected vertices

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, undirected-graph

I want to group non-connected vertices in a graph and minimize the number of these groups. In another word, given a collection of vertices, divide them into minimum number of groups but at the same time no two connected vertices in the same group

Example

[image: here]

Answer should be 3 groups:
the first: 0, 3
the second: 1
the third: 2

I tried to solve it using brute force by storing the graph into adjacency matrix but it's not working.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (!vis[i]) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (!adjMat[i][j] && !vis[j]) {
                vis[j] = true;
            }
        }
        vis[i] = true;
        groups++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to find chromatic number (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring), there's no polynomial solution

Comment: assuming you have a square matrix, try doing an exclusive or with 1s on one side of the diagonal of the matrix. What you are left over are 1's representing the nodes that arent connected.

Comment: ^ Like fas said, NP-complete problem. Hit up the Fields medal guys if you find an efficient solution.

Comment: This is the clique cover problem for the complement of the graph. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover